# Can't Download dependency for Play migration of Streams (Scala/sbt)

Tags: scala, sbt, playback

We upgrade an older system to newer Version of Play (Scala 2.12.8 -> 2.13.5, Play 2.6 -> 2.8)
and now I have this line of Code:

```
Ok.chunked(Source.fromPublisher(IterateeStreams.enumeratorToPublisher(MyEnumerator))).withHeaders(...)
```

In the new project the IterateeStreams seems to be missing, but when I try to add the dependency with

```
libraryDependencies += ....
                       "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-iteratees" % "2.6.1"
                       "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-iteratees-reactive-streams" % "2.6.1"
```

the download fails. I also tried the akka Streams described in  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/StreamsMigration25

But IntelliJ also doesn't knows the "Stream" class. (import akka._ in the class).
I tried playing around with dependecies and stuff, but it seems I can't make it and now I am confused.

I'm still very new to Scala/Play (startet two weeks ago), so may be I just do some rookie-mistakes here...

Error:

```
$ compile
[info] Updating 
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last update for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13:2.6.1
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/******/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13-2.6.1.pom
[error]   not found: https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13-2.6.1.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.akka.io/snapshots/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13-2.6.1.pom
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 26.04.2021, 12:40:02
[myProject] $ last update
[debug] "not up to date. inChanged = true, force = false
[debug] Updating ...
[info] Updating 
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13:2.6.1
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/*******/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13-2.6.1.pom
[error]   not found: https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13-2.6.1.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.akka.io/snapshots/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13-2.6.1.pom
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:247)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$35(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:216)
[error]         at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:216)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:102)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:69)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:96)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:150)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:129)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$5(Defaults.scala:2950)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13:2.6.1
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/******/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13-2.6.1.pom
[error]   not found: https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13-2.6.1.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.akka.io/snapshots/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13/2.6.1/play-iteratees-reactive-streams_2.13-2.6.1.pom
```

It looks like it's trying the default resolver first, and then the custom resolvers. But as far as I understood this, the default one should work.

Btw.: The same dependency was used in the old project in the same way.

Comment: Could you please add the complete error ?

Comment: I added the log from the Terminal.